# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not working when mysql to a remote server

Tags: php, mysql, yii, load-data-infile

I am working on Load data functionality.I have mainly two server, One contain MYsql and other is for web portal.

When I try to perform load local infile using below query it will give me "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version" Error.

```
Query :  "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/btisms/contact_data/".$file_name."' REPLACE 
                        INTO TABLE `tbl_recipient`
                        FIELDS
                        TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                        LINES
                        TERMINATED BY '\n'         
                        (`gr_grp_id`, `gr_cust_id`, `gr_name`, `gr_number`)
                        ".
```

Below steps already perform by me.

1) Add local-infile = 1 into my.cnf and [client] and [mysql] tag.

2) Allow Access for directory in apparmod.

3) Grant file permission to particular user.

4) MySQL Version : 5.5.4 (CentOS-7)

Can any one suggest me if anything is missing.

It's working when i tried to perform this functionality when mysql and web server are on same server.

Comment: You don't mention a restart the MySQL Server after making the changes to the configuration file for the server. (The [mysql] section,)  If your phpmyadmin is using the builtin MySQL client (and not the separately installed mysql client) there's likely a configuration setting in phpmyadmin that does the equivalent of the setting the option in the [client] section for the mysql command line client.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. yes, I done with the restart MySQL and MySQL is separately installed on my server.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a local file.

In case you run in another server (remote or not), you must **ensure** that the file is located in the *same folder location you use in the query*.

If the file is not present, the mysql will not do any action or throw error.

In order to save problems developing Mysql, I recommend you to take a solution like the following:

```
$handle = fopen("your_file", "r");
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, 'your_db_name');
$niceArr = array();

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $lineArr = explode(",", trim($line) );

        foreach($lineArr as $line ) {
            // Remove ""
            $niceArr[] = trim($line, '"');
        }

        // should check if isset($niceArr[ x ])
        $q = "insert into tbl_recipient SET ".
            "gr_grp_id = '$niceArr[0]',".
            "gr_cust_id = '$niceArr[1]',".
            "gr_name = '$niceArr[2]',".
            "remoteaddr = '$niceArr[3]',".
            "gr_number = '$niceArr[4]'";

        $res = mysqli_query( $con, $q );
        if( !empty( mysqli_error($con) ) ) {
            throw new Exception("Error writing line in db: $db_host");
        }

    }
    fclose($handle);
    mysqli_close($con);

} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

This way you can:

- track errors about the file location,
- track errors about non properly formatted lines, and finally
- mysql errors separately.

This will make your life much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

The issue regarding connection in PHP that it may use LOCAL INFILE

**Using mysql:**

```
mysql_connect(server,user,code,false,128); // 128 enables LOCAL INFILE
mysql_select_db(database);
```

**Using mysqli:**

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($conn,server,user,code,database);
```